# sql query for logins for days

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question table:

```
userid       logintime            logouttime
1           1/8/17 10am           1/8/17  9pm
2          1/8/17 9am           1/8/17  10pm
3          1/8/17 11am          1/8/17  6pm
1          2/8/17 11am          2/8/17  7pm
2          2/8/17 6am           2/8/17  4pm
3          2/8/17 8am           2/8/17  3pm
1          3/8/17 4am          3/8/17  1pm
2          3/8/17 11am         3/8/17  11pm
3          3/8/17 5am          3/8/17  5pm
```

I need sql query for the time gap between by a user from 1st day to second day

Example answer table:

```
userid      logintime          logouttime            timegap
1          1/8/17 10am          1/8/17  9pm          25 hours
1          2/8/17 11am          2/8/17  7pm
```

time gap by userid=1 from  1/8/17 10am  to  2/8/17 11am is
 25 hours

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: ms sql server  i am using

Comment: Data type for columns logintime and logouttime?

Comment: date is the data type for logintime and logout time

Answer (score 0):

Below i use a common table expression (CTE)  on your existing table which increments by userid and ordered by logintime earliest to last, then I join this to itself joining on where the row number is +1

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
userid,
logintime,
logouttime,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY logintime ASC NULLS LAST) AS rn
FROM table
)
SELECT 
CTE.userid,
CTE.logintime,
CTE.logouttime, 
(CTE.logintime-CTE2.logintime) AS timegap
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN ON CTE AS CTE2 ON (CTE.rn +1)=CTE2.rn AND CTE.userid=CTE2.userid
```